# React-native setTimer executes immediately

Tags: react-native

I have a problem, where `setTimeout` wrapped functions are called instantly. Instead of 5000ms I specified, it takes randomly between 50ms to 500ms. I tested `setInterval` instead, and strangely the first execution is also almost immediate, but subsequent calls are right on time. I'm testing on android emulator. POC repository: [here](https://github.com/Misiur/TimerBug)

Steps to reproduce:

1. `react-native init TimerBug`
2. Add `console.time('test 1'); setTimeout(() => console.timeEnd('test 1'), 5000);` at the top of index.android.js `render` method.

([exact position for lazy here](https://github.com/Misiur/TimerBug/blob/17febc050f7823196ff9e11816019b0000617d5a/index.android.js#L17-L18))

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Stupid question but, did you try the setTimeout with curly braces too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in React Native that has been popping in the issue tracker for a while now. The problem happens only in debug mode, as in that case, your code is executed on a different JavaScript engine (Chrome's V8 instead of JavaScriptCore). See these issues:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9030
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9436
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4470
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9030

Apparently as of React Native 0.44.0 (Released on May 2017), the problem is still present. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9436#issuecomment-302868758) you can find an interesting fix.